# How does Javascript associative array work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am in bit of a puzzle, recently I had worked on a project where use of javascript was necessary. Everything is working fine I just need to know how does it work

eg :  I had a dynamic variable `count`, which use to get some value, lets say I get the value as `var count = 6;`

Now when I put this  in array `{count : count }`
I get the output as `{count : 6}`

Now my doubt is the output should have been `{ 6 : 6}` as count should have been replaced with its value but it didn't happen so. Why is happening ? and how is this working properly ?

Comment: In JavaScript, that is called an _object literal_ and it functions differently from what you may have come to understand with PHP's associative arrays. If that is literally your code `{count: count}` then you have assigned the variable `count` on the right to the key `count` on the left. If you had used something like `theObj[count] = count`, then you would have ended up with the `{6: 6}` you expected.

Comment: Please post the code with more context so we can see what you attempted.

Comment: You are referencing the variable with it's value in the format javascript wants it. The language just interprets it that way. Try giving us a concrete example

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks for the descriptive answer, I think I get it what you said

Answer (score 1):

The key value pairs treat the key as a literal and the value as a variable.

so:

```
var count = 6;
var o = {count: count};  // results in {count: 6}
```

but to use a variable as the key, you can do this:

```
var count = 6;
var o = {};
o[count] = count;  // results in: {6: 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript object initialisation syntax lets you use bare words. If you do this:

```
{ foo: 6, bar: 12 }
```

It's equivalent to this:

```
{ 'foo': 6, 'bar': 12 }
```

What you want is to assign directly, like so:

```
var foobar = {};
foobar[foo] = 6;
foobar[bar] = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript associative arrays (or most associative arrays for that matter), the left side is the key, and the right side is the value. -> `{key:value}`

When you put `{count:count}` when you have a `count` variable beforehand (let's say its value is 10), what will happen is it will be read as `{count:10}`.

The left-hand side, or the key, is not a variable, but a constant.